# Bootstrap 5 align a card on the screen centre, like: <center></center> used to

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to align a card in the screen center.

This is what I have but it's not working:

```
<div class="d-flex aligns-items-center justify-content-center card text-center w-75">
    <div class="card-header">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="true" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I screen center the card in bootstrap 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `mx-auto` to the outer `div`. however, centering depends on the parent element.
here is a little guide https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

```
<div class="d-flex aligns-items-center justify-content-center card text-center w-75 mx-auto">
    <div class="card-header">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="true" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

for centering with `position:absolute` bootstrap 5 uses `position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle`
[Bootstrap 5 centering](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/position/#center-elements)

```
<div class="d-flex aligns-items-center justify-content-center card text-center w-75 position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
    <div class="card-header">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="true" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's centered now but not vertically centered

Comment: for centering with position:absolute bootstrap 5 uses position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle Bootstrap 5 centering

Comment: There is a typo in `aligns-items-center`. It should be `align-items-center`